# VBA Userform listbox double click event

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform with a listbox displaying all items within a table.
the listbox has a double click event where;
if the row double clicked contains text it opens an edit form.
if the row double clicked is empty then a message box displays stating "the item is not valid for editing."

I'm looking to add a new feature to this where if a certain cell along the row contains "closed" a message box displays stating "this item is closed and not valid for editing.

I'm not very good at VBA and I'd appreciated any help that can be offered. below is the current code I have.

```
Private Sub RiskLogReviewListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

'Checks if the selected row is empty and outputs a message box if it is
    If Len(Trim(RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 0))) = 0 Then _
        MsgBox "The selected item is empty and not a valid entry for editing"

'Checks if the selected row is closed and outputs a message box if it is
    If RiskLogReviewListBox.Column(11, 0) = "closed" Then _
        MsgBox "The selected item is closed and not a valid entry for editing"

'Checks if the selected row is populated
    If Len(Trim(RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 0))) > 0 Then
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution

```
Private Sub RiskLogReviewListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim i As Long

'Checks if the selected row is empty and outputs a message box if it is
    If Len(Trim(RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 0))) = 0 Then _
        MsgBox "The selected item is empty and not a valid entry for editing"

'Checks if the selected row is closed and outputs a message box if it is
    If (RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 10)) = "closed" Then
        MsgBox "The selected item is closed and not a valid entry for editing"
            Exit Sub
    Else

'Checks if the selected row is populated
    If Len(Trim(RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 0))) > 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 If RiskLogReviewListBox.Column(11, 0) = "closed" Then _
```

with

```
If Instr(RiskLogReviewListBox.Column(11, 0), "closed") > 0 Then _
```

But, I suppose that your code must exist in case of the two above situation. So, I would also suggest using of `Exit Sub` after the messages...